# Using ReentrantLock with Multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, locking

I am new to multithreading, and would really appreciate some help.

**EDITED CODE AND QUESTION**

I want to use ReentrantLock class to control access to two ArrayLists. The first is orderList, while the second is a preparedOrders ArrayList. Two objects of Class Chef (which extends Thread) want to remove an order each time from an array list, sleep for a random amount of time, then place the order in the preparedOrders arraylist until the OrdersList is empty. Here is my current code :

***Chef Class***

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Chef extends Thread{

    private String name;
    private ReentrantLock orderLock; 
    private ReentrantLock preparedLock;
    private String orderName;
    private Object useForLocking = new Object();

    public Chef(String name, ReentrantLock orderLock, ReentrantLock preparedLock){
        this.name = name;
        this.orderLock = orderLock; 
        this.preparedLock = preparedLock;
    }

    public void run(){
        while(Restaurant.orderList.size()>0){
            try{
                getOrder();
                System.out.println(name +" is preparing "+orderName+"\n");
                Thread.sleep(Math.round(Math.random()*100));
                outputOrder();
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("run exception: "+e+"\n");
            }
        }
    }

    public void getOrder(){
        if(orderLock.tryLock()){
            orderLock.lock();
            try{
                orderName = Restaurant.orderList.remove(0);
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("getOrder exception: "+e+"\n");
            }finally{
                orderLock.unlock();
                synchronized (useForLocking){
                    useForLocking.notify();
                }
            }
        }else{
            try{
                synchronized (useForLocking){
                    useForLocking.wait();
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("getOrder wait exception: "+e+"\n");
            }
        }
    }

    public void outputOrder(){
        if(preparedLock.tryLock()){
            preparedLock.lock();
            try{
                Restaurant.preparedOrders.add(orderName);
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("outputOrder exception: "+e+"\n");
            }finally{
                preparedLock.unlock();
                synchronized (useForLocking){
                    useForLocking.notify();
                }
            }
        }else{
            try{
                synchronized (useForLocking){
                    useForLocking.wait();
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("outputOrder wait exception: "+e+"\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***Restaurant Class (main)***

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class Restaurant{
    public static ArrayList<String> orderList = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> preparedOrders = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        orderList.add("Cheese Pizza");
        orderList.add("Hotdog");
        orderList.add("Hamburger");
        orderList.add("Cheese burger");
        orderList.add("Chicken Nuggets");
        orderList.add("Chicken Burger");

        ReentrantLock orderLock = new ReentrantLock();
        ReentrantLock preparedLock = new ReentrantLock();

        Chef c1 = new Chef("Chef John", orderLock, preparedLock);
        Chef c2 = new Chef("Chef Mark", orderLock, preparedLock);

        c1.start();
        c2.start();
    }
 }
```

***Output***

```
Chef John is preparing Cheese Pizza
Chef John is preparing Hotdog
Chef John is preparing Hamburger
Chef John is preparing Cheese burger
Chef John is preparing Chicken Nuggets
Chef John is preparing Chicken Burger
```

Why is the first thread not unlocking?

Comment: That's not a very concise question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example / `IllegalMonitorStateException` is thrown because a precondition for calling `notifyAll` or `wait` on an object is for that specific object to be locked with `synchronized`. For `java.util.concurrent.locks` you need to use other methods.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline could you give some sample code?

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline I have edited my code (focusing on chefs only this time), but it still does not provide the wanted functionality. Any help?

Comment: There's an example of using monitor methods with `Lock`s in the `Condition` API docs. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html You need to create a `Condition` with `Lock.newCondition` and ensure that you call  `await` (like `wait`) and `signalAll` (like `notifyAll`) **on the same instance of `Condition`**.

Comment: @NathanHughes obviously. If it was a a simple error I could've just fixed it myself.

Comment: Edited code and question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if your methods each lock the mutex twice, but only unlock it once. They do something like this:

```
if(preparedLock.tryLock()) {   // locks the mutex if the result is true.
    preparedLock.lock();       // This locks it A SECOND TIME.
    try{
        ...
    }finally{
        preparedLock.unlock(); // This unlocks it ONCE.
    }
}
// At this point, the thread still has one lock on preparedLock
```

A `ReentrantLock` object allows a single thread to hold multiple claims on a mutex.  It's useful for situtations like this:

```
private final Lock myMutex = new ReentrantLock();

public void foobar(...) {
    myMutex.lock();
    try {
        ...
    }
    finally {
        myMutex.unlock();
    }
}

public void bizzwizz(...) {
    myMutex.lock();
    try {
        ...
        foobar(...);
        ...
    }
    finally {
        myMutex.unlock();
    }
}
```

Both foobar() and bizzwizz() are public functions.  We want other classes to be able to call either one of them, but we also want both of them to lock `myMutex`, and we want `bizzwizz()` to be able to call `foobar()`.

If myMutex was not reentrant, we'd have a problem when `bizzwizz()` called `foobar()` because `foobar()` would then try to lock a mutex that already was locked. Normally what happens is, the `lock()` call would not return until the lock is released by the thread that owns it. But that's never going to happen because the same thread that owns it is the one that's calling `lock()`.  This situation sometimes is called a *self deadlock*.

A *reentrant* mutex allows a single thread to have multiple claims on the mutex.  Each `lock()` call increments the number of claims by one, and each `unlock()` call decrements it.  Threads B, C, and D will not be able to `lock()` the mutex so long as thread A has *at least* one claim.

Comment: Oh, I though tryLock() only chekced the lock and didnt lock.

Comment: @MohamedMoustafa, The return value from `tryLock()` tells whether it succeeded (locked the lock) or failed. There's also an `isLocked()` method, but `isLocked()` is not very useful except maybe in debugging or performance monitoring code. The problem with `isLocked()` is that no matter what value it returns, you can't depend on it to still be true even one nanosecond later: Another thread may have acquired the lock or released the lock in between the moment when `isLocked()` looked at it, and the moment when your code decides to do something about it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your question. I'm not sure what your question is, but this is something you ought to know.

If you're going to use `Lock` objects, use them like this:

```
myLock.lock();
try {
    doSomethingThatNeedsProtection();
}
finally {
    myLock.unlock();
}
```

This pattern ensures that the code will always leave `myLock` unlocked, no matter what else happens.  The important points are:

- The `lock()` call is outside of the `try { ... } finally { ... }` statement. We don't usually expect the `lock()` call to throw, but if *did* throw, it would be a mistake to subsequently try to unlock it.
- Nothing else comes between the `lock()` call and the `try`. Once the `lock()` has successfully returned, we want to make sure that no `Exception` or `Error` can be thrown that would by-pass the `finally {...}` clause.
- The `unlock()` call is inside the `finally {...}`. This ensures that no matter what else happens, this code snippet will leave the lock unlocked.